# Rust with optional webp-encoding feature

Tags: image, rust, webp

I'm trying to include the [sept 10,2022](https://github.com/image-rs/image/blob/8624b716279d41c1ba5bcd81a38519fbcab7a2ce/src/codecs/webp/encoder.rs) addition of a webp encoder in my image processing tool

so my cargo.toml file has the added feature

```
   image = {version =  "0.24.6", features = ["webp-encoder"]}
```

And use it as such

```
   let fout = &mut BufWriter::new(File::create(path)?);

    webp::WebPEncoder::new(fout).write_image(buf, width, height, color),
```

where buf is image.as_bytes().

It bails with the following:

> Err(Unsupported(UnsupportedError { format: Exact(WebP), kind:
> Color(L8) }))

Anyone use this newish encoder.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre], how are `buf`, `width`, `height` and `color` defined? You probably should also include the `use` statements necessary, if possible avoid anything that needs file system interaction, maybe a `Vec<u8>` can stand in as writer instead of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.6/image/codecs/index.html#supported-formats) `WebPEncoder` supports encoding for `ColorType::Rgb8` and `ColorType::Rgba8` only:

> | Format | Encoding |
> | --- | --- |
> | WebP | Rgb8, Rgba8 |

So you'll need to use one of those instead of `ColorType::L8`.
Of course if your image isn't in `Rgb8` / `Rgba8` already you have to convert it first, as far as I know you have to go through `DynamicImage`:

```rust
use std::io::BufWriter;

use image::{codecs::webp, ColorType, DynamicImage, EncodableLayout, ImageEncoder};

fn main() {
    // should work with any image type really, not just `GrayImage`.
    let gray_image = image::GrayImage::new(10, 20);
    let rgb_image = DynamicImage::from(gray_image).into_rgb8();
    let buf = rgb_image.as_bytes();
    let f_out = &mut BufWriter::new(Vec::new());
    webp::WebPEncoder::new(f_out)
        .write_image(buf, 10, 20, ColorType::Rgb8)
        .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats the issue. Now its a Err(Parameter(ParameterError { kind: DimensionMismatch, underlying: None })) suggesting the width and height is 'mismatched' Both are u32. And no problems for png, jpeg and tiff. At any rate. thanks

Comment: @ABoston that's exactly why it would have been important to know the exact types of `image` and `color` i.e. provide a complete [mre], see my edit